# Error while running bash script as sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

When I run this script as a normal user (not sudo) I don't get any errors and the script runs fine. However when I run it using sudo I get the following errors and the script exits

```
./C12468098_BackupAndRestore.sh: 55: ./C12468098_BackupAndRestore.sh: select: not found
./C12468098_BackupAndRestore.sh: 83: ./C12468098_BackupAndRestore.sh: Syntax error: "do" unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

I can't seem to figure out where the problem lies as the errors suggest some sort of syntax errors but why would these not show up when running as a normal user? Can anyone give me some insight as to what is going wrong?

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

clear

# This function is used to validate yes or no answers inputted by the user
# It was taken from this public GitHub repository https://gist.github.com/davejamesmiller/1965569

ask()
{
    while true; do

        if [ "${2:-}" = "Y" ]; then
            prompt="Y/n"
            default=Y
        elif [ "${2:-}" = "N" ]; then
            prompt="y/N"
            default=N
        else
            prompt="y/n"
            default=
        fi

        # Ask the question - use /dev/tty in case stdin is redirected from somewhere else
        read -p "$1 [$prompt] " REPLY </dev/tty

        # Default?
        if [ -z "$REPLY" ]; then
            REPLY=$default
        fi

        # Check if the reply is valid
        case "$REPLY" in
            Y*|y*) return 0 ;;
            N*|n*) return 1 ;;
        esac

    done
}

# This function adds the cron job to the cron table
add_cron()
{
    crontab -l | { cat; echo "$1 rsync -avbzhe ssh --delete --progress --max-size='10000k' --exclude-from 'exclude_list.txt' / $location;"; } | crontab -;
}

choices="Full_Backup Schedule_Backup View_Scheduled_Backups Restore Quit"

select options in $choices; do
if [ "$options" = "Full_Backup" ]; then
    read -p "Enter the ABSOLUTE path for the backup to be stored " location;

    # Adding the path to the exclude list to avoid an infinite loop
    echo $location >> exclude_list.txt;

    # Making the backup directory in case it doesn't exist already
    mkdir -p $location;

    echo "Starting intial backup";
    rsync -avzhe ssh --progress --delete --max-size='10000k' --exclude-from 'exclude_list.txt' / $location;
    echo -e "\nInitial backup complete!";

elif [ "$options" = "Schedule_Backup" ]; then
    if ask "Would you like to schedule backups to the location previously specified?"; then
        echo $location;
    else
        read -p "Enter the ABSOLUTE path for the backup to be stored " location;
        echo $location >> exclude_list.txt;

        # Making the backup directory in case it doesn't exist already
        mkdir -p $location;
    fi

    echo "How frequently would you like the backup to be done?"

    cron_choices="Annually Monthly Weekly Daily"
    select cron_options in $cron_choices; do
        if [ "$cron_options" = "Annually" ]; then
            add_cron @annually ;
            echo "Annual crontab added. Backing up folder / to location $location";
        elif [ "$cron_options" = "Monthly" ]; then
            add_cron @monthly ;
            echo "Monthly crontab added. Backing up folder / to location $location";
        elif [ "$cron_options" = "Weekly" ]; then
            add_cron @weekly ;
            echo "Weekly crontab added. Backing up folder / to location $location";
        elif [ "$cron_options" = "Daily" ]; then
            add_cron @daily ;
            echo "Daily crontab added. Backing up folder / to location $location";
        fi
    done
elif [ "$options" = "View_Scheduled_Backups" ]; then
    crontab -l;
elif [ "$options" = "Restore" ]; then
    exit;
elif [ "$options" = "Quit" ]; then
    exit;
else
    echo "Please select a valid option";
fi
done

# Removing the user defined path from the exclude list
head -n -1 exclude_list.txt > temp.txt
mv temp.txt exclude_list.txt
```

Comment: `select` is a shell keyword in bash. It may _not_ be a builtin in POSIX sh, (though it is [called out](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_004) as a possible reserved word.)

Comment: …Which makes me think the problem is that `sudo` is attempting for some reason to run this command in `sh`, not `bash`.

Comment: Could you suggest a possible course of action to fix this problem?

Comment: @Briscoooe Do not run `sudo sh /your/script`. Run `sudo bash /your/script`, or if you've added appropriate permissions, `sudo /your/script`

Comment: For the sake of convenience I gave all users execute privileges. To run the script I simply type sudo ./C12468098_BackupAndRestore.sh Is this the correct way?

Comment: Lines mentioned in error don't match the error. Line 55 is comment and line 83 does not contain any "do". weird..